# How to pipe an output of first command to go to specific location of next command?

Tags: bash

I am running a command that spits out IPs, I need to feed it to another program at a specific location as it comes, how do I do it?

```
$ command1 | command2  -c configfile -i "$1" status
```

"$1" is where I want the result of command1 to go to.

Thanks.

Comment: Please add sample Input_file and expected output of your question.

Comment: Do you mean you want a separate instance of `command2` for each line emitted by `command1`, or do you want *all* the lines written by `command1` to be written in a single string passed passed to `command2` in that location?

Comment: If it's the latter, should `command2` get a *filename* that will, when read, have output from `command1`? (So are you running just one copy of `command2`, or are you running one `command2` per line of output from `command1`?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`xargs` is your tool

```
$ command1 | xargs -I {} command2 -c configfile -i {} status
```

you can refer to the argument multiple  times, for example

```
$ echo this | xargs -I {} echo {}, {}, and {}

this, this, and this
```

based on the last comment, perhaps you want to do something like this

```
$ var=$(command1) && command2 "$var" ... | command3 "$var" ...
```

Comment: It's conceivable that this might be what the OP wants, but it doesn't strike me as very clear. I mean, a typical pipeline only runs one instance of the program on each side; `command1 | command2` doesn't do one `command2` per line of output from `command1`, so this is a pretty different semantic.

Comment: @Charles Duffy yes, you're right.  It's a particular solution, not necessarily the right one.

Comment: Yes this question is definitely unclear. Another possibility would be `command2 -c configfile -i "$(command1)" status`

Comment: This is what I want thanks. Now, Is it possible to add 2 lines after 'xargs -I {}' . Something like : command1 | xargs -I {} ; echo 'Changing :' {} ; command2 -c configfile -i {} status

Comment: Is it possible to assign it to a variable and use it later in the pipe ? like : echo this | xargs -I {} echo {}, val={} | echo $val

Answer (score 1):

To pass `command2` a filename which will, when read, provide output from `command1`, the appropriate tool is [*process substitution*](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst):

```
command2 -c configfile -i <(command1) status
```

The `<(...)` syntax will be replaced with a filename -- on Linux, of the form `/dev/fd/NN`; on some other platforms a named pipe instead -- from which the output of `command2` can be streamed.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably 100 ways to do this in a bash shell. This one is quick and easy.  We can use ifconfig, grep the IP address, use awk to pull it out and assign it to an environment variable.  Then use the boolean operator to run the next command which uses the environment variable

```
IPADDR=`ifconfig | grep 172 | awk '{print $2}' | awk -F: '{print $2}'` && echo $IPADDR
```

Comment: I'm not at all convinced that this answers the question. It's not piping content "as it comes" at all (a pipeline runs both programs *at the same time* with the former's stdout connected to the latter's stdin, whereas this runs first the command on the left, and then the command on the right after the one on the left exits).

Comment: ...and as an aside, `grep | awk` is a code smell: Just one `awk` can do the whole job: `ifconfig /172/ { print $2}`, for example. And all-caps variable names are actually reserved for variables defined by the OS or shell -- see the relevant POSIX standard doc @ http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, fourth paragraph.